# Change content based on button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

This image sums up quite easily what I'm trying to do

[image]

The issue is that I can't for the life of me think of what it would be called so it makes it rather hard to google it :)

It's where you click on one of the tabs and it changes the content below. I'm not even asking for code necessarily just what you'd call this so I can do some searching :)

Comment: It's called `tabbed navigation`. Maybe start here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called tabbed panels (or, as @m90 points out: tabbed navigation).  A great example of implementation in Javascript is in the jQuery UI framework. http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ .

For example, after implementing the HTML, all that needs to be called is:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
```

Where `#tabs` is the id of a div that contains the proper markup.